# Modifying the constraint definition of a column

Tags: mysql

I created this table students18, with the column nm varchar(40), in MYSQL

Now when I try to alter this column as

```
alter table students18 modify nm varchar(40) constraint st18nn1 not null;
```

it throws up an error.

Can anyone help me with the correct syntax (for academic purposes I have to do the constraint declaration in the alter table statement)?

Comment: What error does it "throw up"?

Comment: something like, use correct syntax 'constraint st18nn1...' onwards

Comment: Did you read the [documentation on `ALTER TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html)? Make sure your command conforms to the syntax. Also paste the *exact* error whenever possible. It helps immensely.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
ALTER TABLE students18 
MODIFY (nm varchar(40) CONSTRAINT st18nn1 NOT NULL);
```

Comment: Can you give us the  message erreur ?

Comment: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'constraint st18nn1 not null'

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please explain this code (in your answer)? You might get more upvotes that way!